# OpenCV apply 3d lut (.cube) to image

Tags: python, opencv, lookup-tables, color-mapping

I have look all through the docs and it seems as if the cv2.LUT(img, lut) only works on 1d lut files 256 long. I have a 64x64x64 cube lut that I want to apply to an image. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do it with OpenCV at the moment.

However, there is no pretty library for this case, so I wrote a small gist for this case: https://gist.github.com/arsenyinfo/74e42b41749cf29a7bbb69ed839bff1a.

It's not really fast (not optimized in any way), some vectorization would be useful.